# Vaildator for a string on user input

Tags: c++, validation

Hey i want to stop the user from entering integers when i ask the user to input a name.  I have achieved this for an integer and a char.  Can anyone help me adapt my code for a string.

```
int getNum()
{
    int num;
    std::cout << "\nWhat is your age? ";
    while (!(std::cin >> num))
    {
        // reset the status of the stream
        std::cin.clear();
        // ignore remaining characters in the stream
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Enter an *integer*: ";
    }
    std::cout << "You entered: " << num << std::endl;
    return num;
}

char getChar(string q)
{
    char input;
    do
    {
        cout << q.c_str() << endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    while(!isalpha(input));
    return input;
}
```

Comment: You really should initialize your num in the getNum() example. Otherwise it might result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string q = "This is a test123";

for(string::iterator i = q.begin(); i != q.end(); i++)
{
    if((*i < 'A' || *i > 'z') && (*i != ' '))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

would also be an option, if you allow for spaces and other characters.

Edit: updated for checking a single char:

```
char c;
bool finished = false;
printf("Please enter your sex, M/F?\n");
while(!finished)
{
    cin >> c;
    if(!(c == 'm' || c == 'M' || c== 'f' || c=='F'))
    {
        printf("Please try again...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        finished = true;
    }
}
```

Note that c is only input, char by char, when Enter is pressed, before that the line feed does not happen.

Comment: It looks like a good idea.  But i dont understand how to implement it into one of these functions.

Comment: Well, I dont really know what you want to do within your "char getChar(string q)" function. The above code tells you if there are characters outside A..Za..z' ' within your string. If you can tell me what you want exactly, or what the getChar() should return, I can adapt it accordingly.

Comment: Wel basically with the getChar i did this string input = "What is your sex M/F?";
 char sex = getChar(input);  So i need to do something similar.  Basically warn the user that there is a problem and dont continue until there is a valid input.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using std:string, then you can use this to find if the entered string has any digits or not:

```
if (std::string::npos != s.find_first_of("0123456789"))
{
  std::cout << "digit(s)found!" << std::endl;
}
```